# Big Query: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed

Tags: google-bigquery

I was trying to update and tried to save a view but it doesn't respond, and nothing can be saved.
So I used the same query to create a new view but encountered an internal error.
The view is just simply UNION ALL queries something like the below:

SELECT Week, Year,Date_of_Update FROM `a`
UNION ALL
SELECT Week, Year,Date_of_Update FROM `b`
UNION ALL
SELECT Week, Year,Date_of_Update FROM `c`

Does anyone know where should I start with to look for any errors?